Manjaro Crash when Free RAM at about 200MB
My Laptop crashes when my RAM fills up, be that by me being silly with Blender or the cache being filled up. When it crashes, it blinks the caps lock key, which I found would a kernel panic. There's nothing in the journalctl I could find that'd be useful, only normal logs.
This is pretty easily reproducable for me, I create a large file on an external drive and copy it to the internal. It's been happening for a little while now, I tried

Memtest (no fails in 6 runs)
Different Kernels (6.6 and 6.9)
Clearing Disk Space (should it be an issue with writing to disk)

Before I go buy new RAM that may or may not fix the issue, I'd like to ask here. Fastfetch result:
OS: Manjaro Linux Wynsdey 24.0.1 x86_64
Host: Dell G15 5515 (1.14.0)
Kernel: Linux 6.6.32-1-MANJARO
Uptime: 12 mins
Packages: 2111 (pacman)[stable], 44 (flatpak)
Shell: zsh 5.9
Display (NCP005F): 1920x1080 @ 120Hz [Built-in]
DE: KDE Plasma 6.0.5
WM: KWin (Wayland)
WM Theme: Win12OS-dark
Theme: Oxygen (Win11OSDark) [QT], Catppuccin-Mocha-Standard-Rosewater-Dark [GTK2/3/4]
Icons: Win11-black-dark [QT], Win11-black-dark [GTK2/3/4]
Font: Noto Sans (10pt) [QT], Noto Sans (10pt) [GTK2/3/4]
Cursor: Win10OS (24px)
Terminal: kitty 0.35.0
Terminal Font: NotoSansMono-Regular (11pt)
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H (16) @ 4,46 GHz
GPU 1: AMD Radeon Vega Series / Radeon Vega Mobile Series @ 0,72 GHz [Integrated]
GPU 2: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q [Discrete]
Memory: 5,58 GiB / 30,71 GiB (18%)
Swap: 694,00 MiB / 8,00 GiB (8%)
Disk (/): 1,04 TiB / 1,78 TiB (58%) - ext4
Local IP (wlp4s0): 10.0.17.171/23 *
Battery: 47% [Discharging]
Locale: en_US.UTF-8


with 30 GB RAM, I don't think you'll usually need much more (of course, shenanigans done in Blender etc nonwithstanding); even when your system finally runs out, it would just kill the processes that cause the highest memory pressure, log that (so, the logs would contain very useful information, you say yours don't…), and then continue to work – no reason for the kernel to panic.

Soooo, I'm more betting on your storage subsystem, or the file system drivers.

How would I even go about debugging that? Reinstall Linux?

Honestly, I'd go about this very innocently. First, I'd make sure next boot, filesystem checks are run on your internal disk before it gets used. You go into your boot loader, probably GRUB, and edit the kernel command line next boot and add fsck.mode=force and that should check all your internal drives for filesystem errors. If that runs through cleanly, I'd make a backup of all files (not an image) on the volume that gets written when when things crash to an external drive or an encrypted backup to one of these affordable online backup services (backblaze etc), using a live medium.

Armed with that backup, I'd indeed feel a bit freer, because at that point we'd not lose data doing anything stupid. For example: check that journalctl is configured to keep logs across boots, by running journalctl --list-boots. It should list a couple last boots. If it doesn't, ask here how to configure it to permanently store logs on an external drive.

Boots are being logged, and fsck is clean, everything seems fine so far. Backed up the relevant data already, so I'm gonna try reinstalling the FS drivers

that won't help. It's not like there's different ones.

Well how I know myself I could have corrupted it xD

very unlikely, these things are part of your kernel, and unless you were working on your own file system drivers … (and you might have mentioned that you were working on your own file system if you report crashes related to storage). Anyway, unnecessary spending long time convincing someone to not do something unnecessary that only takes minutes: filesystem drivers are part of your kernel, so go ahead and reinstall the kernel package, reboot. Should take the better part of 2 minutes, whether it helps or not ^^"
